# Using a hash sign (#) in a .htaccess search

Tags: html, .htaccess, search, ascii, hashtag

So the jist of this is,
I have a file:

```
search.php
```

When I goto:

```
search.php?search=%23HashTag
```

The search returns: #HashTag

But when I use my .htaccess method:

```
/search/%23HashTag
```

Nothing is returned. And i've tested by putting the number sign later in the search and it returns upto that point.

This is what I have:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^\.]+)$ search.php?search=$1 [NE,L]
```

What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your flags to `[NE,B,L]`.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

mod_rewrite unescapes the url before applying transformations. I'm not sure why it loses anything after the hash (maybe it re-interprets it as a url, and discards the fragment?). In any case, [B] re-escapes the url before running it through the rewrite rule.

Answer (score 0):

Does replacing it with `\%23` work ok?

(Clarity: Opposed to writing the # in the .htaccess file)

Comment: It actually just changes the \ to a forward slash

Comment: Just moved to a FreeBSD apache server, and I notice it doesn't work on that distro.